# What does this equation mean? (related to mean value theorem)

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

$
\pi(x+1)-\pi(x)=\pi'(\xi)[(x+1)-x]=\pi'(\xi)
$

Where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function. This should be related to the mean value theorem, but I don't understand any step of the equation.

Comment: The prime counting function isn't differentiable... ?

Comment: At least it's almost everywhere differentiable... ;)

Comment: Care to point us to where you got such a formula?

Comment: I got it from here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635445/proof-that-the-derivative-of-the-prime-counting-function-is-the-probability-of-p/635490

Answer (score 0):

1. The prime counting function is not continuous, and hence not differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Let $\pi(x)$ be continuous on closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on (a,b). Then mean value theorem states for $[x,x+1]\in [a,b]$:
   $$\frac{\pi(x+1)-\pi(x)}{(x+1)-x}=\pi'(\xi) \implies \pi(x+1)-\pi(x)=\pi'(\xi)$$
   for some $\xi\in (x,x+1)$

Comment: So the squiggly E is a variable for an $x$ value?

Comment: It's a lower case Greek xi (pronounced, "ksee"), and, yes, it's an argument for the function $\pi'$, so it's an $x$-value.